# Force Windows dialog boxes to always display "More details"

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to have Windows copy and move dialog boxes always display the "More details" segment without having to ask every time?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you can do that using the [Classic Shell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/classicshell/) freeware as explained [here](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-always-show-more-details-in-file-transfer-cut-copy-delete-dialog-box-in-windows-vista-and-7/).
You only need to select the Classic Explorer component when installing.

[image: Classic Explorer screenshot]

However, note that installing the program seems to change a couple of settings (which you might not want).

Comment: what "couple of settings" are changed when installing?

Comment: I installed all 3 components of Classic Shell, so as a result the start menu was changed to a classic start menu. Probably easy to undo by checking the right settings. I didn't check any other things for changes though, I uninstalled after that.

Comment: thanks - this works great! (I'm just using the 'Explorer' component - don't want the start menu altered)